1 John 4:9, "God sent His ONLY begotten Son into the world." Jesus is the Son in the exclusive sense. Would this mean the Son has His Father's nature?
I ask because all sons bear the full nature of their fathers. No son ever bore a nature that was not the same nature as his father. In the same way that we being the son of our father, bear a human nature.

This looks like a theological question much more than an exegetical question. It will need to be edited to much more clearly ask about the interpretation of this specific passage rather than about related theological topics. Note that using a passage as a springboard to a related topic is not allowed on this site. This question looks like you're taking the exclusivity of Jesus as a given from this verse, and then asking about general Christology rather than 1 John.

Yes.
[Heb 1:3 ESV] He (Jesus) is the radiance of the glory of God and the exact imprint of his nature, and he upholds the universe by the word of his power. After making purification for sins, he sat down at the right hand of the Majesty on high,

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Simply quoting a verse does not make for a valid answer on this site. Please [edit] this to explain your understanding of the verse and how it addresses the question.

Can Father create the world, or anything, without Christ - who was with Father before the world was created (John 17:5; John 1:1-2) - co-creating? I guess, it is preposterous and mythological to think so; just imagine: Father tells His Son, “let us create man according to Our image” (Gen. 1:26), and the Son responding: “You know, Daddy, I have aided you in creating universe with all galaxies, all animals and plants, is not that enough? Please, make man without Me, for I have some other plans and, moreover, I have a full confidence that your work will have a touch of a true genius!”
Now, since this is impossible and since Father and the Son always act jointly and cannot not act so in Their divine activity (for after Incarnation and adoption of human nature the Son has also human activity which the Father does not), then surely They share one creator-nature.
God Father can do His divine things without even highest of saints, His adopted sons, but He is totally unable, ontologically unable to do any divine deed without His co-eternal Son co-doing the same deed. That is why Christ is His “only-begotten” or “unique” Son, who shares His uncreated, creator nature.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Translation from Greek
Translation of 1 John 4:9: The love of God was made known is us because the King being unique as God, was sent by GOD into the world so that we can live through the King.
The Son of God is a Hebrew idiom that means the King. There is a unique spelling in the Greek which I translated as GOD to distinguish it from God which is an idiom of the Kingly authority from GOD.
1 John 4:9
In this (us) was made known the love of our God in us.
https://biblehub.com/interlinear/1_john/4-9.htm
The verse is saying that GOD here on Earth.
God sent many into the world. John the Baptist was also sent. The Son gave himself to the world. Sent and given are not the same meaning.
John 1:6 There was a man sent from God, whose name was John.
John 3:16, For God so loved the world. Therefore the Son, the Son gave so that everyone believing in the Son would not persist, but have eternal life (Spirit of God)
John 3:16 equates the Son as being God because through the Son we have the Spirit of God.
All the word endings in Greek within John 3:16 are the same so it cannot be distinguished what the subject and object are. The subject and object are the same.
The verse does not imply that God is the same as the Father whom the Son revealed to be the supreme deity of the Elohim. God is an adjective of this mystery of the divine and supernatural deities, not a specific noun or person.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
